# HttpClient does not work in asp.net (works in Postman)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, request, put

I  tested this code and it worked first time; now I get empty response. However, with Postman I am able to get the response. It seems that Json is not read correctly. I get back a 400 error.

```
private Guid GetToken()
{
var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = "url";
var jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Authorization());

var response = client.PutAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
var x = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

if(x=="")
    return Guid.Empty;

return new Guid(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}

public class Authorization
{
    public string _x;
    public Guid _y;
    public Guid _z;
    public long _a;
    public long _b;

    public Authorization()
    {
        x = 123; //dummy data
        y = xx-xx-xx-xxxxx-xx-xxxx;
        z = xx-xx-xx-xxxxx-xx-xxxx;
        a = 123;
        b = 123;
    }
}
```

Comment: Http code 400 stays for "Bad request". It means the backend of your application cannot handle the given request. Maybe you mixed up the method (Get/Post) with Postman and your real application.

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to declare the transport method?

Comment: The method is PUT, in fact i haven't changed anything. This is correct var response = client.PutAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. The problem was the name of the attributes in the `Json object`.

I used `Resharper` and that renamed my variables in the `Json object` from **Id** to **_id** (note the underscore).